# Using playwidget with customized scene update functions (like play3d)

Tags: r, rgl

`play3d` supports customized scene update function, i.e., you can do basically do whatever you want from frame to frame, including adding/updating shapes, surfaces, lighting, or viewpoint. See `demo(flag)` where the surface of the flag is redrawn every frame.

`playwidget` is somewhat more limited. It only supports `par3dinterp`-style controls that can be passed in order to update `par3d`. If you want to change attributes of the 3d plot beyond the elements available in `par3d`, e.g., adding a shape, I don't see how you can do it.

Is there a way to make `playwidget` behave similarly to `play3d`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three ways to do it.

If you have a fairly limited number of changes (like a simple version of the flag example), you can plot all the frames at once, and set all but one of the objects to `alpha = 0` which makes it invisible.  Then change which frame gets `alpha = 1` in response to the playwidget.

Another way to do it is to write Javascript.  The first example in the `Legacy WebGL Methods` vignette does this.  Be aware that the internal structure of the rgl objects in Javascript is subject to change, so this may be hard to maintain.

A final way is to use Shiny.  Make the changes in R code, and the replot the scene.  `demo("shinyDemo", "rgl")` does this.